# If a set $Y$ is separable, prove that $\mathrm{cl}(Y)$ is also separable.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Suppose we are working in a metric space $(X,d)$.

Let $Y$ be a separable subset of $X$. By definition, this means that there exists a $countable$ subset $S\subseteq Y$, where $S$ is dense in $Y$.

The definition I am using for "$S$ is dense in $Y$" is: $\ \ \ S \cap B(y;r) \neq \emptyset$ for all $y \in Y$, and all $r>0$.

Now I want to show that $\mathrm{cl}(Y)$ is also separable.
(Meaning, I need to show that there exists a countable subset $S_{c}\subseteq \mathrm{cl}(Y)$, where $S_{c}$ is dense in $Y$. Meaning, where $S_{c} \cap B(y_{c};r_{c}) \neq \emptyset$ for all $y_{c} \in \mathrm{cl}(Y)$, and all $r_{c}>0$).

By definition, the closure of $Y$, $\mathrm{cl}(Y)$, is the set:

$\mathrm{cl}(Y)=\{ \ x \in X \ | \ B(x;r) \cap Y \neq \emptyset \mathrm{\ for\ all\ }r>0\ \}$

MY ATTEMPT:

Take any $y_{c} \in \mathrm{cl}(Y)$. Then $B(y_{c};r) \cap Y \neq \emptyset \mathrm{\ for\ all\ }r>0$.

I thought about setting $S_{c}=S$. Obviously, $S_{c}$ is countable. Also, we know that $Y \subseteq \mathrm{cl}(Y)$, which means that $S_{c} \subseteq \mathrm{cl}(Y)$.

I tried combining these two statements:

$S_{c} \cap B(y;r) \neq \emptyset$ for all $y \in Y$, and all $r>0$.
$B(y_{c};r) \cap Y \neq \emptyset \mathrm{\ for\ all\ }r>0$.

to say that $S_{c} \cap B(y;r) \neq \emptyset$ for all $r>0$, which would complete the proof.

However, this cannot be so easy. I think I am overlooking something.

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

- A set $S$ is dense in $Y\subseteq X$ if and only if $Y\subseteq\overline{S}$.
- $\overline{\overline{S}}=\overline{S}$, and $A\subseteq B\to\overline{A}\subseteq\overline{B}$.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I try and show that $\bar{S}$ is dense in $\bar{Y}$? If so, how can we be sure that this will work, since I think $\bar{S}$ is not necessarily countable?

Comment: @Greg.Paul You were correct to take $S^c=S$. You are trying to show that $S$ is dense in $\overline{Y}$, but this translates to $\overline{Y}\subseteq\overline{S}$, which you should be able to prove given the rules I mention here for closure. (Given your from-first-principles proof attempt, this may mean that you now are tasked with proving these rules for your definition of closure in a metric space, if you don't already know them.)

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't understand. So $S$ is dense in $Y$ means that $Y\subseteq\bar{S}$ (I remember seeing this). So for $y_{c}\in\bar{Y}$, we have $B(y_{c};r)\cap Y \neq \emptyset$ for all $r>0$. This implies that $B(y_{c};r)\cap \bar{S} \neq \emptyset$ for all $r>0$.  How can I show that this implies $B(y_{c};r)\cap S \neq \emptyset$ for all $r>0$?

Comment: @Greg.Paul This is the content of the assertion $\overline{\overline{S}}=\overline{S}$, which if you don't already "know" you will have to prove. (If you know that this is true in a topological space, and you know that a met.sp. is a top.sp. then that is one way to get the result.) But your comment is on the right track. Given $r>0$, take some $z\in B(y,r/2)\cap\bar S$. Then $B(z,r/2)\cap S\ne\emptyset$. Can you show $B(z,r/2)\subseteq B(y,r)$?

Comment: I'm almost there! Let $y_{c}\in\bar{Y}$. We know $B(y_{c};r) \cap Y \neq \emptyset$ for all $r>0$ by definition of $\bar{Y}$. But $Y\subseteq\bar{S}$, and so $B(y_{c};r) \cap \bar{S} \neq \emptyset$. Let $r>0$. Take $z \in B(y_{c};\frac{r}{2}) \cap \bar{S}$, we find that $B(z;\frac{r}{2}) \cap S \neq \emptyset$ (by definition of $\bar{S}$). For any $p \in B(z;\frac{r}{2})$, we have $d(p,y_{c})\leq d(p,z)+d(z,y_{c}) < \frac{r}{2} + \frac{r}{2} = r$, and so $p \in B(y_{c};r)$. Then $B(z;\frac{r}{2}) \subseteq B(y_{c};r)$.  (continued below)

Comment: (continuing the above)....For this reason, $B(z;\frac{r}{2}) \cap S \neq \emptyset$ implies $B(y_{c};r) \cap S \neq \emptyset$. This seems good to me - Where do I need to use $\bar{\bar{S}}=\bar{S}$? Thank you!

Comment: @Greg.Paul You are actually proving $\bar{\bar S}=\bar S$ here, which is the hardest part of the proof of the theorem you want - the rest is trivial. Just consider that the assertion $y\in\bar{\bar S}\to y\in\bar S$ is exactly what you said to begin with: "suppose we know that $B(y,r)\cap\bar S\ne\emptyset$ for all $r>0$, how can I show that this implies $B(y,r)\cap S\ne\emptyset$ for all $r>0$?" (PS: Your proof is correct.)

Comment: If you *use* $\bar{\bar S}=\bar S$ as a lemma, then the proof is simply: "Suppose $S$ is dense in $Y$. Then $Y\subseteq\bar S$, so $\bar Y\subseteq\bar{\bar S}=\bar S$. Thus $S$ is dense in $\bar Y$. QED"

Comment: Thank you - That is very helpful!